# Git revert a commit and add changes even after more commits followed

Tags: git, version-control, git-rebase, git-revert

My use case is very usual.

I added a commit, that went through my build system. Some post-commit tests on the build system failed. The system is configured to revert such a commit.

So the System also added a `Reverting back revision my-commit`.

Now, I added the fixes to correct the build. But someone else made 2 commits on top of the revert that went in successfully before I could push in mine.

So now my state is:

```
$ git log

commit good-commit1 
author: good-dev1
...

commit good-commit2
author: good-dev1
...

commit good-revert-commit
author: system
...

commit my-bad-commit
author: me
...
```

Both `good-commit1` and `good-commit2` **change files which I modified** in `my-bad-commit`.

How do I add my fixes on top of `my-bad-commit`, or revert the `good-revert-commit` and add fixes on it, and then re-apply the other dev's good commits?

**Note**: our system doesn't allow `-f` (force push) to the master branch.

Comment: Since your `master` branch is not allowed force push, you can only use `git revert` the the top of commit history. Else you can use `git rebase -i` or replace current `master` branch etc.

Comment: did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just revert the revert with

```
git revert good-revert-commit -n
```

`-n` is a synonym for `--no-commit` here.

So the changes will be in the index, then `git add` your additional changes, finish the commit and push.